# Switching Control and fn keys does not work

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

I want to switch my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>fn</kbd> keys. It's a MacBook Pro 2019 with 12.4 and a Touch Bar.

**Keyboard** > **Modifier Keys**:

```
Control (^) Key: fn Function
Function (fn) Key: ^ Control
```

But it just doesn't work. My <kbd>fn</kbd> key still works as <kbd>fn</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

Is this a known bug?

Comment: Are you using Karabiner-Elements? This software ignores the remapping made through `System Preferences… > Keyboard`.

Comment: No, I don't use that program.

Comment: Which version of MacOS are you running?