# Switching Ctrl and Fn key won't work on macOS Ventura

Tags: keyboard, ventura

I have a MacBook Pro M1 with macOS Ventura and I cannot get my external keyboard to work in the same way as the internal one. The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys are reversed, so <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is the outermost key.

Keeping the key bindings work fine. Reversing them though doesn't do anything. I've tried this with two different keyboards, one wired and another Bluetooth, and it's the same thing. The problem is that I don't want to change my typing style when I switch from external to internal, and since I use the Terminal a lot, I need <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd> <kbd>Del</kbd> to work as they should.

Is this a known issue in Ventura, and if so, how do I get this fixed? I saw this other related [post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/441476/switching-control-and-fn-keys-does-not-work) which no one has answered. I do not have any other software like Karabiner-Elements.

Comment: So it's hopeless?

Comment: As currently implemented by Apple, yes unfortunately.

Comment: Unfortunate. Thanks for the answer though, @Allan

Comment: @irene the only people I know who can fix this is the developers themselves. Try reporting to https://www.apple.com/feedback/macos.html. if not the manufacturer would provide a driver for it.